# Disparateness in Simple pendulum plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to plot the normalized approximate solution of x against the parameter h in simple pendulum. On the graph are two solutions that overlap (One for exact and the other for numerical). Please, can anyone show me how to distinctively draw the graphs. I want something like dashline and triangle, for dissimilarity. Here are my codes.

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{Hle1Values[[i]], yle1Values[[i]]/Subscript[\[Theta], 
     0]}, {i, 1, Steps}], PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Thick}];


p2 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{Hle1Values[[i]], approx11[[i]]/Subscript[\[Theta], 0]}, {i, 
     1, Steps}], PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];


Show[p1, p2, AxesLabel -> {"h", "x"}]
```

The graph is given below

[image: Equation of x vs h]

For data set

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{\text{yle1Values}[[i]]}{\theta _0} & \text{Hle1Values[[i]]} & \frac{\text{approx11}[[i]]}{\theta _0} \\
 0.999602 & 0.00513408 & 2.09355 \\
 0.998408 & 0.0102682 & 2.091 \\
 0.996416 & 0.0154022 & 2.08675 \\
 0.993624 & 0.0205363 & 2.08079 \\
 0.990027 & 0.0256704 & 2.07312 \\
 0.985621 & 0.0308045 & 2.06373 \\
 0.9804 & 0.0359386 & 2.05262 \\
 0.974358 & 0.0410726 & 2.03976 \\
 0.967486 & 0.0462067 & 2.02516 \\
 0.959777 & 0.0513408 & 2.00879 \\
 0.951222 & 0.0564749 & 1.99065 \\
 0.941811 & 0.061609 & 1.97072 \\
 0.931535 & 0.0667431 & 1.94898 \\
 0.920384 & 0.0718771 & 1.92541 \\
 0.908346 & 0.0770112 & 1.90001 \\
 0.895413 & 0.0821453 & 1.87275 \\
 0.881574 & 0.0872794 & 1.84362 \\
 0.86682 & 0.0924135 & 1.8126 \\
 0.851142 & 0.0975475 & 1.77968 \\
 0.834532 & 0.102682 & 1.74483 \\
 0.816982 & 0.107816 & 1.70806 \\
 0.798486 & 0.11295 & 1.66934 \\
 0.779041 & 0.118084 & 1.62868 \\
 0.758644 & 0.123218 & 1.58605 \\
 0.737294 & 0.128352 & 1.54146 \\
 0.714992 & 0.133486 & 1.49492 \\
 0.691742 & 0.13862 & 1.44641 \\
 0.667551 & 0.143754 & 1.39597 \\
 0.642428 & 0.148888 & 1.34359 \\
 0.616386 & 0.154022 & 1.2893 \\
 0.589439 & 0.159157 & 1.23313 \\
 0.561607 & 0.164291 & 1.1751 \\
 0.532913 & 0.169425 & 1.11527 \\
 0.503382 & 0.174559 & 1.05368 \\
 0.473044 & 0.179693 & 0.990381 \\
 0.441934 & 0.184827 & 0.925445 \\
 0.410088 & 0.189961 & 0.858943 \\
 0.377547 & 0.195095 & 0.790956 \\
 0.344357 & 0.200229 & 0.721575 \\
 0.310565 & 0.205363 & 0.6509 \\
 0.276224 & 0.210497 & 0.579037 \\
 0.241388 & 0.215631 & 0.506101 \\
 0.206115 & 0.220765 & 0.432215 \\
 0.170465 & 0.2259 & 0.357508 \\
 0.134501 & 0.231034 & 0.282115 \\
 0.0982873 & 0.236168 & 0.206176 \\
 0.0618909 & 0.241302 & 0.129836 \\
 0.0253789 & 0.246436 & 0.0532421 \\
 -0.0111807 & 0.25157 & -0.023456 \\
 -0.0477193 & 0.256704 & -0.100108 \\
 -0.0841686 & 0.261838 & -0.176564 \\
 -0.120461 & 0.266972 & -0.252676 \\
 -0.15653 & 0.272106 & -0.328298 \\
 -0.192309 & 0.27724 & -0.403288 \\
 -0.227736 & 0.282374 & -0.477509 \\
 -0.262749 & 0.287509 & -0.550828 \\
 -0.297289 & 0.292643 & -0.623122 \\
 -0.331301 & 0.297777 & -0.694272 \\
 -0.36473 & 0.302911 & -0.764168 \\
 -0.397529 & 0.308045 & -0.832707 \\
 -0.42965 & 0.313179 & -0.899796 \\
 -0.46105 & 0.318313 & -0.96535 \\
 -0.491692 & 0.323447 & -1.02929 \\
 -0.52154 & 0.328581 & -1.09155 \\
 -0.550563 & 0.333715 & -1.15208 \\
 -0.578733 & 0.338849 & -1.21081 \\
 -0.606026 & 0.343983 & -1.2677 \\
 -0.632421 & 0.349118 & -1.32273 \\
 -0.657903 & 0.354252 & -1.37585 \\
 -0.682458 & 0.359386 & -1.42705 \\
 -0.706074 & 0.36452 & -1.47631 \\
 -0.728744 & 0.369654 & -1.52362 \\
 -0.750465 & 0.374788 & -1.56897 \\
 -0.771232 & 0.379922 & -1.61235 \\
 -0.791047 & 0.385056 & -1.65378 \\
 -0.80991 & 0.39019 & -1.69325 \\
 -0.827827 & 0.395324 & -1.73078 \\
 -0.844802 & 0.400458 & -1.76637 \\
 -0.860841 & 0.405592 & -1.80004 \\
 -0.875953 & 0.410726 & -1.8318 \\
 -0.890146 & 0.415861 & -1.86166 \\
 -0.90343 & 0.420995 & -1.88964 \\
 -0.915814 & 0.426129 & -1.91576 \\
 -0.927308 & 0.431263 & -1.94004 \\
 -0.937923 & 0.436397 & -1.96249 \\
 -0.947669 & 0.441531 & -1.98312 \\
 -0.956555 & 0.446665 & -2.00196 \\
 -0.964592 & 0.451799 & -2.01901 \\
 -0.971788 & 0.456933 & -2.0343 \\
 -0.978151 & 0.462067 & -2.04783 \\
 -0.98369 & 0.467201 & -2.05962 \\
 -0.988412 & 0.472335 & -2.06968 \\
 -0.992323 & 0.47747 & -2.07801 \\
 -0.995427 & 0.482604 & -2.08464 \\
 -0.997729 & 0.487738 & -2.08955 \\
 -0.999233 & 0.492872 & -2.09276 \\
 -0.99994 & 0.498006 & -2.09427 \\
 -0.999851 & 0.50314 & -2.09408 \\
 -0.998967 & 0.508274 & -2.09219 \\
 -0.997285 & 0.513408 & -2.0886 \\
 -0.994804 & 0.518542 & -2.08331 \\
 -0.99152 & 0.523676 & -2.0763 \\
 -0.987429 & 0.52881 & -2.06758 \\
 -0.982525 & 0.533944 & -2.05714 \\
 -0.976803 & 0.539079 & -2.04496 \\
 -0.970254 & 0.544213 & -2.03104 \\
 -0.962871 & 0.549347 & -2.01536 \\
 -0.954646 & 0.554481 & -1.99791 \\
 -0.945569 & 0.559615 & -1.97867 \\
 -0.93563 & 0.564749 & -1.95763 \\
 -0.92482 & 0.569883 & -1.93478 \\
 -0.913128 & 0.575017 & -1.9101 \\
 -0.900544 & 0.580151 & -1.88356 \\
 -0.887058 & 0.585285 & -1.85516 \\
 -0.87266 & 0.590419 & -1.82487 \\
 -0.857342 & 0.595553 & -1.79269 \\
 -0.841094 & 0.600687 & -1.7586 \\
 -0.82391 & 0.605822 & -1.72257 \\
 -0.805783 & 0.610956 & -1.68461 \\
 -0.786707 & 0.61609 & -1.6447 \\
 -0.76668 & 0.621224 & -1.60284 \\
 -0.7457 & 0.626358 & -1.55901 \\
 -0.723767 & 0.631492 & -1.51323 \\
 -0.700885 & 0.636626 & -1.46548 \\
 -0.677059 & 0.64176 & -1.41579 \\
 -0.652296 & 0.646894 & -1.36416 \\
 -0.626609 & 0.652028 & -1.31061 \\
 -0.600011 & 0.657162 & -1.25517 \\
 -0.572521 & 0.662296 & -1.19786 \\
 -0.544159 & 0.667431 & -1.13872 \\
 -0.514949 & 0.672565 & -1.07781 \\
 -0.484921 & 0.677699 & -1.01516 \\
 -0.454107 & 0.682833 & -0.950857 \\
 -0.422542 & 0.687967 & -0.884954 \\
 -0.390266 & 0.693101 & -0.817533 \\
 -0.357323 & 0.698235 & -0.748683 \\
 -0.323759 & 0.703369 & -0.678498 \\
 -0.289624 & 0.708503 & -0.607083 \\
 -0.254974 & 0.713637 & -0.534549 \\
 -0.219863 & 0.718771 & -0.461018 \\
 -0.184352 & 0.723905 & -0.386614 \\
 -0.148503 & 0.72904 & -0.311471 \\
 -0.112378 & 0.734174 & -0.235727 \\
 -0.0760451 & 0.739308 & -0.159525 \\
 -0.0395699 & 0.744442 & -0.0830125 \\
 -0.00302068 & 0.749576 & -0.00633709 \\
 0.0335342 & 0.75471 & 0.0703507 \\
 0.0700263 & 0.759844 & 0.146901 \\
 0.106388 & 0.764978 & 0.223164 \\
 0.142551 & 0.770112 & 0.298993 \\
 0.17845 & 0.775246 & 0.374245 \\
 0.214022 & 0.78038 & 0.448781 \\
 0.249203 & 0.785514 & 0.522465 \\
 0.283933 & 0.790649 & 0.595172 \\
 0.318157 & 0.795783 & 0.66678 \\
 0.351818 & 0.800917 & 0.737176 \\
 0.384868 & 0.806051 & 0.806253 \\
 0.417257 & 0.811185 & 0.873916 \\
 0.448942 & 0.816319 & 0.940076 \\
 0.479883 & 0.821453 & 1.00465 \\
 0.510043 & 0.826587 & 1.06757 \\
 0.53939 & 0.831721 & 1.12878 \\
 0.567894 & 0.836855 & 1.18821 \\
 0.59553 & 0.841989 & 1.24582 \\
 0.622277 & 0.847123 & 1.30158 \\
 0.648115 & 0.852257 & 1.35544 \\
 0.673031 & 0.857392 & 1.40739 \\
 0.697013 & 0.862526 & 1.45741 \\
 0.720052 & 0.86766 & 1.50547 \\
 0.742141 & 0.872794 & 1.55158 \\
 0.763279 & 0.877928 & 1.59573 \\
 0.783464 & 0.883062 & 1.63792 \\
 0.802696 & 0.888196 & 1.67815 \\
 0.82098 & 0.89333 & 1.71644 \\
 0.83832 & 0.898464 & 1.75278 \\
 0.854722 & 0.903598 & 1.78719 \\
 0.870193 & 0.908732 & 1.81969 \\
 0.884742 & 0.913866 & 1.85029 \\
 0.898378 & 0.919001 & 1.879 \\
 0.91111 & 0.924135 & 1.90584 \\
 0.922949 & 0.929269 & 1.93083 \\
 0.933904 & 0.934403 & 1.95398 \\
 0.943986 & 0.939537 & 1.97532 \\
 0.953205 & 0.944671 & 1.99485 \\
 0.961571 & 0.949805 & 2.0126 \\
 0.969092 & 0.954939 & 2.02857 \\
 0.975778 & 0.960073 & 2.04278 \\
 0.981636 & 0.965207 & 2.05525 \\
 0.986675 & 0.970341 & 2.06598 \\
 0.9909 & 0.975475 & 2.07498 \\
 0.994317 & 0.98061 & 2.08227 \\
 0.99693 & 0.985744 & 2.08784 \\
 0.998744 & 0.990878 & 2.09171 \\
 0.99976 & 0.996012 & 2.09388 \\
 0.99998 & 1.00115 & 2.09435 \\
 0.999405 & 1.00628 & 2.09312 \\
 0.998033 & 1.01141 & 2.0902 \\
 0.995863 & 1.01655 & 2.08556 \\
 0.992891 & 1.02168 & 2.07923 \\
 0.989114 & 1.02682 & 2.07117 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: The input should be provided in cut-and-pastable form.Please post All actual code rather than an image of code.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk. Alright, let me try.

Comment: Yours code dosen't work .Please post minimal working code?.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk. It wouldn't work except I present the data set. I have just provided the data set. You can hover your way around it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **demo**  code  below:

```
$Version
(* "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

Steps = 10;
p1 = ListPlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 1, Steps, 0.5}], 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[RightTriangle]", 20}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
AxesLabel -> {"h", "x"}, PlotLabel -> "DATA 1 and DATA 2", 
PlotLabels -> {"DATA 1"}, PlotLegends -> {"DATA 1"}];
p2 = ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Sin[i] + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {i, 1, Steps, 0.1}],
PlotLabels -> {Callout["DATA 2", {Scaled[0.5], Above}]}, 
PlotLabels -> {"DATA 2"}, PlotLegends -> {"DATA 2"}];

Show[p1, p2] (* See in Help : Show -> Possible Issues. *)
```

[image]

**EDITED:**

Using `PlotMarkers`. You can choose symbols form: `Palettes-> Basic Math Assistant->Typesetting->`.

```
Steps = 10;
p1 = ListPlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 1, Steps, 0.4}], 
PlotMarkers -> {"\[RightTriangle]", 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red}];(*ListPlot Not ListLinePlot*)
p2 = ListLinePlot[
Table[{i, Sin[i] + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {i, 1, Steps, 0.1}],
PlotStyle -> {Black}];
Show[p1, p2, AxesLabel -> {"h", "x"}]
```

[image]

**Alternative:**

Execute this code below:

```
Graphics[Polygon[CirclePoints[3]], ImageSize -> 20]
```

Hover over graphics, right mouse button -> Copy Graphics then paste to PlotMarkers.
.

[image]

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk. Thank you very much! It was really helpful! One more thing, how can I plot triangle instead of the green color?

Comment: @Omojola. I edited ma answer.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk. I am very grateful for this. God bless you!

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk, please how can I label the first one? It seems not work here. You know we are combining ListPlot and ListLinePlot. Kindly edit the first example.

Comment: @Omojola.I edited first example.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk, I am very happy for your selfless effort. More to your wisdom in Jesus name!

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk, please, the code is not working. My system is of 32-bits. Is there a way it could be done? Sorry for the stress!