# Problems using Callout in ListPlot and ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-8

I'm trying to plot the solution of Van der Pol's oscillatory equation. However, I encounter a problem each time I combine *Callout, ListPlot and ListLinePlot*. My Mathematica version (*Mathematica 8.0 on 32-bits Computer*) continues to breakdown whenever I decide to plot their Legend on the same graph. Actually, Mariusz Iwaniuk has answered me (see [Disparateness in Simple pendulum plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166940/disparateness-in-simple-pendulum-plot)) but made use of another version which was not compatible with mine. When I pasted it on my Mathematica version, it failed to work. I tried reaching him but couldn't. Howbeit, I really appreciate him. Now, the particular problem's solution is $y=\sin t$. The question is genuine as we intend to submit the paper soon. I'll also love if more than two plots of $\sin t$ using *Callout, ListPlot and ListLinePlot* are plotted together. Normally, I need to plot about six solutions of $\sin t$ (same domain) on the same graph and make one legend for all. For intance, here are the codes and graphs

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

p1 = ListPlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 1, Stepst, 0.5}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[RightTriangle]", 20}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"h", "x"}, PlotLabel -> "DATA 1 and DATA 2", 
  PlotLegend -> {"DATA 1"}]

p2 = ListLinePlot[
  Table[{i, Sin[i] + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]}, {i, 1, Stepst, 0.1}],
   PlotLabels -> {Callout["DATA 1", {Scaled[0.5], Above}]}, 
  PlotLegend -> {"DATA 2"}]

Show[p1,p2]
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone provide a solution or an alternative?

Comment: Use the documentation that comes with your version of Mathematica.  M8.0 does not support `Callout`.

Comment: @  Szabolcs. I don't understand you!

Comment: Assuming that you are asking why this code does not work: Mathematica version 8.0 does not support `Callout`. However, you should phrase the question better.  I cannot see an actual question in this post.

Comment: @  Szabolcs. I have done that!

Comment: `Callout` was introduced in v11, so it won't work in your version.

Comment: @ rcollyer. Any way out?

Comment: Remove the `PlotLabels` option, entirely, it's a 10.4 option. Then, it should combine without issue, well you'll still have to move the legends around, and I can't help with that, I don't know the ``PlotLegends` `` package.

Comment: @  rcollyer. I have tried it before but still had the same problems. It would plot but not on thesame domain. Meanwhile, I removed the PlotLabels you told me to remove. It only brought out "DATA 2" as legend.

Comment: You could maybe simplify your question, as "How can I do [...] with Mathematica 8"?

Comment: Don't use uninformative phrases such as "I'm having problems with..." or "Difficulty in using..." in a title.  Also, your problem has nothing whatsoever to do with van der Pol's equation, so delete it from the title.

Comment: @  David G. Stork. The problem I'm solving is a kind of Van der Pol equation. The solution is $sin t$. Thank you for the corrections.